# MEAN stack deployment on PaaS

Tags: google-app-engine, mean-stack, google-cloud-platform, paas, mean.io

Which PaaS (platform as a service) to consider for auto-scaling MEAN stack. Have previously used Google App Engine for REST Api web development. I am looking for something similar (to GAE) which autoscales MEAN.

Comment: btw, you can run MEAN on Google App Engine using Managed VM. Or with Cloud Containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choice suggestion is [Heroku](https://heroku.com/).

Heroku is a platform as a service (PaaS) that enables developers to build and run applications entirely in the cloud.

Second choice suggestion is [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/index.php).

If you want to make your own decision on pros-n-cons [Heroku vs AppFog](https://www.itcentralstation.com/product_reviews/heroku-review-28970-by-pau-kiat-wee)